# PHP - Проверка поля на заполнение нужного значения

Tags: php

```
 <input type="text" name="Order[qiwi_payment]" class="from form_exchange_field input_icon_ruble_sign" placeholder="Введите сумму в рублях">
```

Имеется такой код.
Как прикрутить сюда проверку суммы (минимальное значение должно быть 900)?

Comment: Use the `minlength` attribute, Luke!

Comment: привет! да это тоже подходит!
но нужна не проверка колл-в чисел. а что бы меньше 900 ввести было нельзя

Comment: атрибут "min" - не работает

Comment: Ах да, неправильно понял, простите.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `input[type='number']` и атрибут `min`:

```html
<form>
<input type='number' min='900' />
<input type='submit' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил вариант на js т.к. поддерживает атрибут `min` ie10 и более

```js
function minv(e, m) {
  if (e.target.value < m) {
    e.target.value = m;
  } 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" onchange="minv(event, 900)">
```